# Split a Column in multiple columns according to a specific string

Tags: text-processing

I have a file with an unique column and I would like to split this column in multiple columns according to a specific string (chr)

Input looks like this:

```
chr10:127293562-127293909
BRUNOL4(Hs/Mm)
CPEB4(Hs/Mm)
CUG-BP(Hs/Mm)
DAZAP1(Hs/Mm)
ENOX1(Hs/Mm)
FMR1(Hs/Mm)
chr11:49214073-49214804
BRUNOL4(Hs/Mm)
BRUNOL5(Hs/Mm)
CPEB2(Hs/Mm)
CPEB4(Hs/Mm)
CUG-BP(Hs/Mm)
HNRNPC(Hs/Mm)
```

The output should look like this:

```
chr10:127293562-127293909  chr11:49214073-49214804
BRUNOL4(Hs/Mm)             BRUNOL4(Hs/Mm)
CPEB4(Hs/Mm)               BRUNOL5(Hs/Mm)    
CUG-BP(Hs/Mm)              CPEB2(Hs/Mm)
DAZAP1(Hs/Mm)              CPEB4(Hs/Mm)    
ENOX1(Hs/Mm)               CUG-BP(Hs/Mm)
FMR1(Hs/Mm)                HNRNPC(Hs/Mm)
```

Any idea would be really appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '/^chr/{i++} 
           {print > "_aux" i }
       END {system( "paste _aux* | column -tn; rm _aux*")}' file
```

- the first 2 lines (with `print > "_aux" i`), split the input into a set of files `_aux1` ... `_auxn` (each file = a column)
- in the end, `paste _aux* | column -tn` pastes and format the parts.

This solution can deal with several columns (I hope).

Answer (score 1):

It is a typical awk problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{ col = -1; l = 0; r = 0; width = 0; }
/^chr[0-9]+:/ {
        ++col;
}
{
        if ( col == 0 ) {
                L[l++] = $0;
        } else {
                R[r++] = $0;
        }
        if ( length ($0) > width ) {
                width = length ($0) ;
        }
}
END {
        for ( i = 0; i < l; ++i ) {
                printf "%-*s %s\n", width, L[i], R[i];
        }
}
```

Call that script "foo" and make it executable,l and pipe your data to it:

```
./foo < foo.in
```

giving

```
chr10:127293562-127293909 chr11:49214073-49214804
BRUNOL4(Hs/Mm)            BRUNOL4(Hs/Mm)
CPEB4(Hs/Mm)              BRUNOL5(Hs/Mm)
CUG-BP(Hs/Mm)             CPEB2(Hs/Mm)
DAZAP1(Hs/Mm)             CPEB4(Hs/Mm)
ENOX1(Hs/Mm)              CUG-BP(Hs/Mm)
FMR1(Hs/Mm)               HNRNPC(Hs/Mm)
```

That assumes the left/right columns have the same number of items, and that you have only two columns.  awk has only one-dimensional arrays.  If your problem requires more columns (say, an arbitrary number), the solution in awk (or preferably perl) would be more complicated.  For that, you would need a clearer question to resolve how to do *that*.

Comment: indeed is more complicated, because i have several "chr" characters in the starting column and there is not a stable number of items in between the first "chr" and the second, the third etc..

Comment: Then you need to ask new questions to resolve those points :-)

Comment: cool! +1, good printf formating option!